# Possible to hide Linq and other extensions from Intellisense without removing the `using`?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Sometimes I notice that my Intellisense gets cluttered with extension methods I don't use that often and simply want to see what's available in the current object.

Is there any way I can hide extensions from intellisense?

Right now I remove the `using System.Linq` and other extensions when working with unfamiliar objects, and add it back in so I can compile

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsable.Advanced)]` to your own code to hide some methods. Some IDE tools (like Resharper) and some extensions in the VS Gallery can modify or replace the Intellisense menu to make them more functional.